# Attaching legs to a table

Tags: wood

I am in the middle of upgrading my computer table and decided to make the table myself so I can customize various parts. I have hit a problem with attaching the legs to the table. The legs are 34mm square pine and the top is 9mm MDF.

I would like (ideally) to have the legs easily removable and height adjustable but am having some trouble on how to accomplish this. I have tried looking for plates that I can attached to the MDF and slot the legs into, but have had no luck.

This is what I had in mind to attach to the top and slide the feet into, but I have honestly got no idea what they're called and so cannot search for them!

[image: Table leg feet]

Comment: I can't find anything like what you describe, but what about turning a [leg cap](https://www.google.com/search?q=leg+cap+metal&tbm=isch) upside down?

Comment: As long as it has some way of fixing it to the underside of the top so the leg can sit inside then yes, the images you've linked appear to be void of any base plate which would allow this, but thank you as it certainly helps!

Comment: [These](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Waddell-Metal-Table-Leg-Straight-Top-Plate/3044351) plates are good for attaching legs to a table.  The leg would then have a threaded stud in the top to screw into place.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That would be fantastic if I was in the USA, alas I am UK based. But that's the best thing I've got so far! Thanks, will endeavour into finding them.

Comment: @Thunder, The product listing and description should at least give you something to search for.  Also, consider IKEA.  They have similar plates and cheap legs that you could steal mounting hardware from.